# What is MetaData in OpenText LiveLink?

Tags: opentext

Can anyone help me in understanding MetaData and Categories, and how can we link to Document?

Comment: This is not actually a question. It is vaguely formulated and it touches a broad user scenario. There is no concrete answer to it that would fit to this forum and would be helpful to its readers.  It is like you'd asked "how to use the C++ language to write a program". And you misspelled the OpenText Livelink product name. I suggest you delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, its Opentext and not Openlink.

Metadata and categories is a part of taxonomy. When you upload a document in Livelink, you can set the metadata fields in Livelink.

Answer (score 1):

Metadata is the collection of Categories and Attributes of a Node in Content Server.

```
Node
  -->Metadata
    -->Category[0]
        -->Attributes DataValues (StringValue, BooleanValue etc...)
    -->Category[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Opentext Content Server (formerly Livelink), metadata are the default information to a document (or any object) provided by the Content Server like the creation date, created by, modified by...

Categories and attributes are additional metadata provided by the customer, as in you can create your category with customized attributes, and assign the category to any folder or document in Content Server, and in addition assigning specific values to the attributes.  Metadata and categories help users in narrowing their search results.